# Select multiple film category

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I am having trouble with my small film database tag/category query.

My table is:

```
ID(index),Name(film name),category
```

One movie can have multiple categories.

```
SELECT Name  FROM categorytable WHERE category ='Action';
```

Works fine but if I want other tags I get empty cursor:

```
SELECT Name  FROM categorytable WHERE category ='Action' AND category ='Sci-Fi';
```

Example select:

```
1  Film001        Action
2  Film001        Sci-Fi
3  Film002        Action
```

EDIT:
My home databese:

```
ID|NAMEFILM|DESCRIPTION
```

And complete query is:

```
SELECT DATABASEFILM.NAMEFILM , DATABASEFILM.DESCRIPTION , NAME from DATABASEFILM , CATEGORY where DATABASEFILM.NAMEFILM=NAME AND category=(SELECT NAME  FROM CATEGORY WHERE category ='Action');
```

Comment: Did you try `OR`? `SELECT Name  FROM categorytable WHERE category ='Action' OR category ='Sci-Fi'`;

Comment: `WHERE category IN ('Action', 'Sci-Fi');`

Comment: When i use OR query works but find all 'Action' films but not not necessarily 'Sci-Fi'.

Comment: @user2091726 - You probably want to use three tables.  One for the movies, one for the categories, and one that links a movie to a category.  With that schema, there's plenty of ways to query for all movies that have a certain set of categories.

Comment: If you could look at the edit post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your query doesn't work is because each row has only one category.  Instead, you need to do aggregation.  I prefer doing the conditions in the `having` clause, because it is a general approach.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM categorytable
group by Name
having sum(case when category ='Action' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when category ='Sci-Fi' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each clause in the `having` is testing for the presence of one category.  If, for instance, you changed the question to be "Action films that are *not* Sci-Fi", then you would change the `having` clause by making the second condition equal to 0:

```
having sum(case when category ='Action' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when category ='Sci-Fi' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: This isn't right. If you group by category, you end up with one row per category. No row of your grouped result can get a positive count for matching two different categories, because the rows contributing to the result row all have the same category. I think you meant to group by Name.

Comment: @SteveKass . . . Good catch.  That should be `group by Name` as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OR clause, or if you have multiple categories it will probably be easier to use IN

So either

```
SELECT Name FROM categorytable WHERE category ='Action' OR category ='Sci-Fi'
```

Or using `IN`

```
SELECT Name 
FROM categorytable 
WHERE category IN ('Action', 'Sci-Fi', 'SomeOtherCategory ')
```

Using IN should compile to the same thing, but it's easier to read if you start adding more then just two categories.

Comment: But what if i want example films which are "Action" AND "Sci-Fi" not only "Action"?

Answer (score 0):

```
with mustAppear(category) as (
  select 'Action'
  union all
  select 'Sci-Fi'
)
  select Name -- select those film names for which
  from categorytable as C1
  where not exists ( -- there is no category that must appear with that name
    select M.category
    from mustAppear as M
    where not exists ( -- that does not.
      select *
      from categorytable as C2
      where C2.Name = C1.Name
      and C2.category = M.category
    )
  )
```

You can also be more direct this way:

```
select Name
from categorytable
where category = 'Sci-Fi'
intersect
select Name
from categorytable
where category = 'Action';
```

The advantage of the former query is that you can use it without modification if you create a permanent table (mustAppear, or you can use a table variable @mustAppear) to hold the category list that must match. The latter query is simpler, but it must be rewritten when the categories change.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sqlite tag, but if you have a permanent table called MustAppear with the required categories, you won't need the WITH clause and should have no trouble using the body of the first query.